# population-dynamics versus population-ecology

Tags: discussion

The standard tag term for population studies is population-dynamics, however, it is also common to see the term "population ecology" for this subject. "Population ecology" is a somewhat more encompassing term for the subject area because it covers studies of population environments, not specifically involving dynamics, but also includes dynamics.

Should "population ecology" be another tag, or would be better to replace "population-dynamics" with "population-ecology"?

Answer (score 2):

Beside the comments from @arboviral, there is also a bit of overlap between the current [population-dynamics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population-dynamics) and [population-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population-biology), so adding [population-ecology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population-ecology) might be redundant. I'm not saying that it's unreasonable, but from a search/discovery perspective it is better to have fewer tags, and the currently presemt [population-dynamics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population-dynamics) and [population-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population-biology) might suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for a separate tag. There is a large body of work specifically on models of population dynamics and questions about that would be more accurately described by the narrower `population-dynamics` tag.